# Disable SPDY connection on retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using retrofit in an android project, the problem is that when user connected to proxy or VPN the IP address that query from HTTP REST API does not change due to connection reuse.

The log show that it is using SPDY - `OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: spdy/3.1` is there anyway to request retrofit to use HTTP 1.1 or disable connection reuse/SPDY on specify route or whole retrofit without touching server side?

Previously when using okhttp, I'm using the method below before each calls. (Which is a very bad idea)

```
ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getDefault();
pool.evictAll();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable SPDY you can use [setProtocols](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html#setProtocols-java.util.List-):

```
ArrayList<Protocol> protocolList = new ArrayList<Protocol>();
protocolList.add(Protocol.HTTP_1_1);

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setProtocols(protocolList);

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(API_URL)
    .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
    .build();
```